# Finding the distance between 2 vectors in a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

In Exercise 20, let $V = P_2$ with inner product
$$\langle p, q\rangle  = \sum_{i=0}^2 p_i q_i$$

a. Find the distance between the vectors $p$ and $q$.
b. Find the cosine of the angle between the
vectors $p$ and $q$.

20. $p(x) = x − 3$, $q(x) = 2x − 6$

The solution listed gives the distance as the radical of 10 and the cosine as 1, but I don't understand why. Detailed steps for calculations would be appreciated as I am getting different answers from the solution manual which is very brief.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $10 = (1-2)^2+(-3-(-6))^2$

Comment: $p(x)=p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0$ with $p_2=0,p_1=1,p_0=0$ (think at it and compute the inner product of a couple of polynomials of degree 2)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get how you reached those numbers for p1,p2, and p0. Also, I don't see how you got the numbers in your first post.

Comment: Well, once you'll get how to find the $p_i$'s you will probably understand how to get 10. A few more examples might be helpful:
If $p(x)=129x^2+21x+5$, then $p_2=129,p_1=21,p_0=5$. If $p(x)=3x^2+2x+1$, then $p_2=3,p_1=2,p_0=1$.
If $p(x) = a x^2 + b x+c$, then $p_2=a,p_1=b,p_0=c$. Do you understand how to get the $p_2,p_1,p_0$ from a given polynomial in $V$?

Comment: I understand now, but in my question: p(x) = x-3. Wouldn't that make p2=0, p1=1, and p0=-3 or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you're totally correct. In the same way $q_2=0$.

Comment: Now, you can also compute inner products in $V$ and the rest follows. Got it?